# Is it possible to make these sql updates all in one update statement?

Tags: t-sql

Is it possible to combine these 4 updates into a single update statement?

```
DECLARE @field_id1 INT = (SELECT field_id FROM t_field WHERE nme = 'first name')
DECLARE @field_id2 INT = (SELECT field_id FROM t_field WHERE nme = 'last name')

UPDATE t_report 
SET grp_field_id = @field_id2
WHERE nme like '%Service report%' and grp_field_id = @field_id1
UPDATE t_report 
SET subgrp_field_id = @field_id2
WHERE nme like '%Service report%' and subgrp_field_id = @field_id1
UPDATE t_report 
SET subsubgrp_field_id = @field_id2
WHERE nme like '%Service report%' and subsubgrp_field_id = @field_id1
UPDATE t_report 
SET subsubsubgrp_field_id = @field_id2
WHERE nme like '%Service report%' and subsubsubgrp_field_id = @field_id1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If this is functional code already, and not causing a significant performance hit it may be better suited for Code Review.

Comment: You can use `case` expressions, e.g. `set subsubgrp_field_id = case when nme like '%Service report%' and subgrp_field_id = @field_id1 then @field_id2 else subgrp_field_id end`, to pile several different column updates into one statement, but that doesn't really clarify things. (The `where` clauses need to be merged to cause the `update` to hit all of the affected rows.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write this:

```
DECLARE @field_id1 INT = (SELECT field_id FROM t_field WHERE nme = 'first name')
DECLARE @field_id2 INT = (SELECT field_id FROM t_field WHERE nme = 'last name')

UPDATE t_report 
SET grp_field_id = IIF(grp_field_id = @field_id1, @field_id2, grp_field_id),
    subgrp_field_id = IIF(subgrp_field_id = @field_id1, @field_id2, subgrp_field_id),
    subsubgrp_field_id = IIF(subsubgrp_field_id = @field_id1, @field_id2, subsubgrp_field_id),
    subsubsubgrp_field_id = IIF(subsubsubgrp_field_id = @field_id1, @field_id2, subsubsubgrp_field_id),
WHERE nme LIKE '%Service report%' 
AND @field_id1 IN(grp_field_id, subgrp_field_id, subsubgrp_field_id, subsubsubgrp_field_id)
```

[`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is syntactic sugar for simple [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression -

```
IIF(condition, whenTrue, whenFalse)
```

is equivalent to

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN whenTrue ELSE whenFalse END
```